# Python - DOCX table comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two MS word documents which contain tables. Tables from file-2 is derived from file-1 and having in-place updates in file-2. For example -

Table from file-2:

[image: Table from file-2]

Table from file-1:

[image: Table from file-1]

To find the difference between two tables, I'm thinking to first tables in document then convert it into JSON format then create a pandas dataframe for it then perform diff (compare) operation on it.

*Note: I'm not sure if it's the correct approach.*

I've been able to extract data in JSON format with python simplify_docx.

```
import docx
import pandas as pd
from simplify_docx import simplify
file1= 'file1.docx'
file2='file2.docx'
# read in a document 
my_doc = docx.Document(file1)

# coerce to JSON using the standard options
my_doc_as_json_std = simplify(my_doc)

# print (json.dumps(my_doc_as_json_std, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_doc_as_json_std)
display(data)
```

**Extracted JSON**

```
{
    "TYPE": "document",
    "VALUE": [
        {
            "TYPE": "body",
            "VALUE": [
                {
                    "TYPE": "paragraph",
                    "VALUE": [
                        {
                            "TYPE": "text",
                            "VALUE": "Sample heading"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "TYPE": "table",
                    "VALUE": [
                        {
                            "TYPE": "table-row",
                            "VALUE": [
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "Column1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "Column2"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "Column3"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "Column4"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "TYPE": "table-row",
                            "VALUE": [
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "A1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "A2"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "A3"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "A4"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "TYPE": "table-row",
                            "VALUE": [
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "B1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "B2"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "B3"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "TYPE": "table-cell",
                                    "VALUE": [
                                        {
                                            "TYPE": "paragraph",
                                            "VALUE": [
                                                {
                                                    "TYPE": "text",
                                                    "VALUE": "B4"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**

[image]

I think I need to iterate over whole JSON file and create dataframe cell by cell. How can I fix this output dataframe in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Because of how your json is parsed, you need to first filter the path from which you want to recover the values, while keeping notice of what level accounts for a row. Given the json you have provided (which I'm calling `example`) this seems to work:

```
rows = json.dumps(example['VALUE'][0]['VALUE'][1]['VALUE'])

df = pd.read_json(rows)['VALUE'].map(lambda x:[w['VALUE'][0]['VALUE'][0]['VALUE'] for w in x]).apply(lambda r: pd.Series(r))
```

This returns the table, but without proper headers, therefore to make the first row as headers and remove it, we can use:

```
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(index=0)
```

Outputting:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1      A1      A2      A3      A4
2      B1      B2      B3      B4
```